# Best Alternative to Approximate the Sqrcfamily Font Which Seems Not to Recognize Accents

Tags: fonts, xetex, formatting, accents, french

I would like, for example, to type the French word Pens{'{e}}es with the sqrcfamily font; however, it seems that the sqrcaps package cannot handle accents.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{sqrcaps}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}
\Huge 
\noindent With smallcaps: \\[15pt]
\hspace*{35pt} \textbf{\scshape{Pens{\'{e}}es}}

\vskip 55pt

\noindent With sqrcfamily font: \\[18pt]
\hspace*{45pt} {\textcolor{red}{\LARGE\selectfont\scalefont{3}\textbf{\sqrcfamily{Pens{\'{e}}es}}}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

QUESTION: Is there a way to override this problem so I may use the sqrcfamily font to type such words? If not, can someone suggest a font *currently* available to LaTeX users that closely resembles the said font? I am using XeLaTex for the document that is requiring such formatting but I have observed the problem will also occur with PdfLaTex as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic: In order for `\textbf{\scshape{Pens{\'{e}}es}}` to be rendered in small-caps, you need to run \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico OP mentioned that problem persisted when using pdflatex. And there is no tag for xelatex

Comment: @I.Chekhov - There are tags for  `pdftex` (which was used) and for `xetex` (which was not used).

Comment: @David Carlisle Please kindly reread the question: "the problem will also occur for Pdflatex as well."

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I will add xetex.

Comment: yes sorry Mico:-)

Comment: The screenshot you posted definitely looks like it was created with pdfLaTeX (and without loading the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`).

Comment: @Mico I complied it both ways; it is possible that I took the PDflatex picture. And the output was run without `fontenc` as I was not aware that I needed it prior to your comment.

Comment: For reference: The Open Type version of the "Bookhand" legacy-format fonts, including the 1st century BC Roman Square Capitals, are currently flagged as 'Under development' (http://www.alterlittera.com/al_htm/bookhand.htm). Unrelated: "Cogitationes" would suit that style font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the closest is another free paleographical font, Klaus-Peter Schaeffel’s [0400 Vergilius Sangallensis](https://www.xn--schffel-7wa.ch/de_gruppe1.html). Because it’s faithful to its manuscript models, it has no small caps. Using it  with `pdflatex` would require lots of work, but with `xelatex` or `lualatex` it’s as easy as this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{0400_vergilius_sangallensis.otf}
\begin{document}
\Huge
Pensées (or Pens\'{e}es)
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You may also like his [2004 Capitalis Quadrata](https://www.xn--schffel-7wa.ch/de_gruppe3.html).

Comment: This font is very nice and would suit my needs; however, when I run your code with Xelatex, after a while, it returns the error that 0400_vergilius_sangallensis.otf cannot be found. Do you have any idea as to why this error may have occurred. Is this a font that was made available to Latex users recently?

Comment: It’s not in CTAN; you have to download it from the site I linked to.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was afraid of that as I have never been able to do this successfully in the past. That's why I asked for a font currently available to Latex users. Perhaps my choice of words wasn't clear. In any case, is there a good set of instructions available somewhere that you could kindly point me to so that I may try to download the font into the proper place so that XeLatex can identify it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: With `fontspec`, any well made and properly encoded OpenType or TrueType font is available to you, but how you install it depends on your operating system. I use GNU/Linux, where I simply put the font in `/home/therese/.fonts/` and then issue the command `fc-cache -frvv`. There are also some GUI programs for installing fonts on Linux. I don’t know about other operating systems, but searching for ‘install font’ and the name of your operating system should produce useful results.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: @I.Chekhov as Thérèse said you can install via `fc-cache` or you can simply save the file in the same directory as your tex file.

Comment: @Thérèse Sorry for not having given you the check mark earlier. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As suggested in your answer, the Klaus-Peter Schaeffel fonts are free, and this seems to be the case since September, 2013. Would you happen to know if this includes commercial use? I would like to use one or more of his fonts in a book to be published, and I have come across nothing that prohibits such usage. I am hoping that you may know for sure. Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians All info is at https://www.schäffel.ch/allgemein_de.html

Comment: Many thanks! If I am interpreting the content correctly, it seems that the fonts are now freely available  for "professional" use: `The fonts may be used without restriction for private and professional purposes. They come complete and with all embed rights. Please refrain from any modification of the data sets, distribution under other names, distribution on websites other than this one or incorporation into font packages.' Thanks again.